# How to merge a successful login's state data via selenium into Requests session?

Tags: python, selenium, python-requests

Sure, my current need can be done by selenium, but it has drawbacks: it is slow, it will require open a real browser on your computer.

My plan is something like: use `selenium` to login to get some state data, then use these data to establish a session via `requests`, so I can make other frequently post requests (such as submit comments or posts to this site) faster.

My try is to directly modify a session's attributes but it failed with error `requests.cookies.CookieConflictError: There are multiple cookies with name, 'tx3_sid'`.

The reason for my try is that when purely using `requests`:

```
import requests

loginUrl = "http://tx3.netease.com/logging.php?action=login"
# postUrl = "http://tx3.netease.com/post.php?action=reply&fid=22&tid=3966375"

client = requests.session()
r = client.get(loginUrl)
r.encoding='gb18030'

print(client.cookies)

# Will get: <<class 'requests.cookies.RequestsCookieJar'>[<Cookie tx3_sid=kkfBk7 for .netease.com/>, <Cookie PHPSESSID=6vctcjdrg1mrig6h0kndmuurn4 for tx3.netease.com/>]>
# So I try to get tx3_sid and PHPSESSID via selenium and set the attributes in requests `client.cookies`
```

This is my try:

```
import requests
import json
import re
from os.path import dirname, realpath
from time import sleep
from selenium import webdriver

USERNAME = "smaller9@163.com"
PASSWORD = "111111"
loginUrl = "http://tx3.netease.com/logging.php?action=login"
postUrl = "http://tx3.netease.com/post.php?action=reply&fid=22&tid=3966375"

# create a driver
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
# get the homepage
driver.get(loginUrl)

un_elm = driver.find_element_by_id("username")
pw_elm = driver.find_element_by_id("ori_password")
submit = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("[name=loginsubmit]")

un_elm.send_keys(USERNAME)
pw_elm.send_keys(PASSWORD)

# click submit
submit.click()

for d in driver.get_cookies():
    if d['name']=='tx3_sid':
        tx3_sid = d['value']
    elif d['name']=='PHPSESSID':
        phpsessid = d['value']
print(tx3_sid, phpsessid)
# above are all OK. varibles `tx3_sid` and `phpsessid` are set.

# -------------------below is requests part. ------------------------
client = requests.session()
client.get(loginUrl)
# cookies are set
print(client.cookies['tx3_sid'],client.cookies['PHPSESSID'])
# here is my try -- failed
client.cookies['tx3_sid'] = tx3_sid
client.cookies['PHPSESSID'] = phpsessid

# so the following cannot be tested yet.
r = client.get(postUrl)
r.encoding='gb18030'
# grab `formhash` which is needed for post dict.
formhashPat = re.compile('<input type="hidden" name="formhash" value="([\d\w]+?)" />')
formhash = formhashPat.search(r.text).groups()[0]
answerData={
    'message':'this_is_post_content', 
    'formhash':formhash,
    'subject':'',
    'usesig':1,
}
client.post(url=postUrl, data=answerData)
```

Update, finally I find a way to modify cookie value:

```
# here is my try -- failed
rck = client.cookies._cookies
#print(rck, type(rck))

for domain in rck:
    for path in rck[domain]:
        for name, cookie in rck[domain][path].items():
            if name == 'tx3_sid':
                cookie.value = tx3_sid
            elif name == 'PHPSESSID':
                cookie.value = phpsessid
```

But then the session no longer support futher requests, so maybe this whole way is unworkable.

Answer (score 1):

The dictionary interface offered by the `requests` is limited in what it can do with cookies.

Apart from a name, a cookie also has a domain and path, both of which are left empty when you set a cookie with `client.cookies[name] = value`. The *existing* cookies have a domain and path associated with them, and if you want to replace these you'll either need to remove them first or match their domain and path.

Deleting them first is easiest:

```
del client.cookies['tx3_sid'], client.cookies['PHPSESSID']
client.cookies['tx3_sid'] = tx3_sid
client.cookies['PHPSESSID'] = phpsessid
```

This creates new cookies with blank paths and domains, meaning they'll be used for all requests without specific domain and path matches.

The alternative would be to loop over `client`, find the matching cookie object and alter these directly:

```
for cookie in client.cookies:
    if cookie.name == 'tx3_sid':
        cookie.value = tx3_sid
    elif cookie.name == 'PHPSESSID':
        cookie.value = phpsessid
```

Comment: This method doesn't work, but you remind me to check source code. I succeed in replacing value in eack cookie object, and then the session can no longer support further request. I guess merging cookie value is not a good idea. I might try others.

Comment: @xiang: you'd have to use the [`CookieJar` API](https://docs.python.org/2/library/cookielib.html#cookiejar-and-filecookiejar-objects) then to find the cookie objects and set the value directly on those.